# using :include && :conditions in a ruby on rails SQL request?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, request

Hey I'm trying to figure something out..

I want to get all **Carts** that have a **cart_stage.stage** equal to '35' (this is a separate table and a cart has many stages)

the cart_stage table is a bit like

**id ----- cart_id ----- stage**

1  ------- 123 ---------- 20

2  ------- 123 ---------- 35

3  ------- 102 ---------- 35

I am trying this at the moment:

```
# Cart model
  has_one :top_stage, :foreign_key => 'cart_id', :class_name => "CartStage", :order => 'stage'

# Cart controller
  @carts = Cart.find :all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :include => :top_stage, :conditions => ["top_stage.stage = ?", 35]
```

This gives me :

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: top_stage.stage: SELECT DISTINCT "carts".id FROM "carts" WHERE (top_stage.stage = 35)  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

Hope it all makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated,

Alex

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out my self actually.. What I wanted was -

```
@carts = Cart.find :all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :joins => :top_stage, :conditions => { :cart_stages => { :stage => 35 } }
```

Thanks for all the help guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

That should probably be:

```
@carts = Cart.find(:all, :order => 'carts.created_at DESC', :include => :top_stage, :conditions => { "cart_stages.stage" => 35 })
```

Remember that you use the name of the table in the conditions, not the name of the association, however you do use the name of the association in the `include` option.

Whenever possible, you should probably use the hash method for expressing conditions to keep your declarations simple. It's when you need complicated `OR` or `>` type logic that the array-style proves necessary.

A better way of expressing it for Rails 3 is:

```
@carts = Cart.order('carts.created_at DESC').include(:top_stage).where('top_stages.stage' => 35)
```

It's not clear why your `cart_stages` table isn't being added with a `JOIN`.

Comment: This gives me:

    SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cart_stages.id: SELECT "carts"....

and how would you go about using the JOIN, I'm a bit in experienced with DB requests in ruby! I'm using Rails V 2.3.8 btw! thanks for the help so far !

Comment: btw the SQL error message was longer but I can't post it all as it was too long to fit in the box!

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere that you include literal SQL, you need to use the real table and column names, **not** the Rails association names.  So you need to have: `:conditions => ["cart_stage.stage = ?", 35]` instead of `top_stage`